# Fiber Channel adapter statistics Linux

Tags: linux, fiber

Anyone know how to get Fiber Channel adapter performance statistics out of Linux? I.E throughput.

Answer (score 3):

You can treat it like normal I/O device and collect information using iostat during high I/O/. You can also use tools like iozone.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the files in `/sys/class/fc_host/hostX/statistics` (where `X` is the number of your HBA), computing a rate from the absolute numbers.
The number are in hex (0x...) for some obscure reason. This works for Emulex (lpfc) and Brocade (bfa) HBAs at least.